# Unable to change java version GNU/linux

Tags: java, linux, configuration, installation, java-8

Tried setting sym links and all but didn't work.
It is pointing to a read only file system.

`bash-4.1$ sudo ln -s /scratch/mbhamba/work/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java /usr/bin/java`

`bash-4.1$ which java
/usr/dev_infra/platform/bin/java
bash-4.1$ sudo rm -f /usr/dev_infra/platform/bin/java
rm: cannot remove /usr/dev_infra/platform/bin/java': Read-only file system`

`bash-4.1$ sudo ln -sf /scratch/mbhamba/work/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java /usr/dev_infra/platform/bin/java
ln: cannot remove /usr/dev_infra/platform/bin/java': Read-only file system`

Comment: instead of trying to remove or soft link the path , add the new path to the $PATH variable at start

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you set (and use) the environment variables `JAVA_HOME`<sup>**1**</sup> and `PATH`<sup>**2**</sup> (with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can usually set them in your `$HOME/.bashrc`)

```
export JAVA_HOME="/scratch/mbhamba/work/jdk1.8.0_40"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

<sup>**1**<sub>The Java home variable is honored by JBoss and eclipse (as well as other common Java projects & containers).</sub></sup>
<sup>**2**<sub>The `PATH` controls where, and the order in which, bash looks for executable commands.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

I would propose another solution, without touching the system default `/usr/bin/java`.

Change for the user `mbhamba` the login script and amend the `PATH` setting to

```
export PATH=/scratch/mbhamba/work/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/:${PATH}
```

That way the JDK 1.8.0_40 would be taken if you compile and execute your code.